# Vector Space that is a Sequence Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider the sequence

$(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ $  |$ $ x_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}f(i)$

then if $f(i)$ can also be viewed as a sequence

$(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ $ |$ $y_n=f(n)$.

Both of these sequences reside in the set of all possible sequences $K$. If they also happen to reside in a subset of $K$ which is a field then they form vector spaces $V$ where

$(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ and $(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N} \in V$.

Then $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ and is a linear combination of $(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$

**Question**

Is $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}=n(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ and hence $\sum_{i=0}^{n}=nf(n)$

Comment: I know this is wrong but where is the fault in my reasoning.

Comment: Is the problem that $nf(n)$ is actually the solution to the finite sum, of the limit of $(y_n)$ as $n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: I suspect that the summation index $i$ is supposed to play a role, but exactly which role? Also, I don't see a natural way for a subset of the sequence space to form a field (except in a few degenerate cases). About the final question: Hard to say, because it is unclear what the question really is. Please go through it at least once more. If I have to guess what the question is, then I will answer "No!". Try with small values of $n=2,3,\ldots$

Comment: What may be confusing to you is that in the space $K$ the addition and scalar multiplication involves entire sequences, but your notation suggests that you operate on individual elements of the sequences. It may be that the confusion is just notational oversight, but often it is symptomatic of a misunderstanding of exactly what the vector space operations are.

Comment: well the addition of ever single element is fine I get that. If you have two sequences (infinite sets) the addition of the two is the addition of every single nth element, which is fine. But when that is all said and through what stops me from then taking a single finite element of the resulting sequence?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27630/discussion-between-marshal-craft-and-jyrki-lahtonen).

Comment: A sequence is most emphatically not a set. It is a function from $\Bbb{N}$ to a space, here most likely the field of real numbers.

Comment: Expand them:
$$(x_n)=(f(0),f(0)+f(1),f(0)+f(1)+f(2),f(0)+f(1)+f(2)+f(3),\ldots)$$
$$n(y_n)=(0,f(1),2f(2),3f(3),\ldots)$$
These are not the same sequence.

Comment: And there is only one sequence $(y_n)$, so I don't understand what you mean by $\sum_{i=0}^n(y_n)$? You still haven't explained how the summand here depends on $i$. I suspect this is close to the core reason of your misunderstanding.

Comment: But where is the flaw in the reasoning above, if you consider sequences to be distinct, that is two sequences  that are the same; are the same sequence. then they do in fact form a set of all possible sequences. If the sequence is a function from $\Bbb N \to \Bbb F$ where $\Bbb F $ is a field, then do they form a vector space? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space I interpret that they do.

Comment: What do you mean by a linear combination of $(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$? There is just one sequence. It is like asking about a linear combination of $\mathbf{i}$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Comment: And, yes, sequences form a vector space (the operations are given in that Wikipage). It may be better to think of a sequence as a vector with (countably) infinitely many components:
$$(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}=(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots).$$ The operation are componentwise. Just like in $\Bbb{F}^n$.

Comment: The whole sequence (you are right is not same as set) $(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ can be viewed as a vector in a vector space. Therefore there can be linear combinations of it, and one such is the repeated sum of $(y_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$.

Comment: To me a tell-tale sign of confusion at some level is that you use $n$ in a dual role. As a limit of summation and also as an index of the sequences. One or the other has to go.

Answer (score 2):

The question is still unclear. I am collecting points from the exchange of comments that may be relevant, and need to be made clear. I also try to describe what I think the question is about, and what kind of misconceptions may exist.

---

We have been given a function $f:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{F}$, where $\Bbb{F}$ is some field. From this function we have built two sequences
$$
(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}},\quad x_n=\sum_{i=0}^n f(i),
$$
and
$$
(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}},\quad y_n=f(n).
$$
So if we want to treatt individual entries of these two sequences, they look like
$$
(x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)=(f(0),f(0)+f(1),f(0)+f(1)+f(2),\ldots),
$$
and
$$
(y_0,y_1,y_2,\ldots)=(f(0),f(1),f(2),\ldots).
$$
AFAICT the question is about the relation of the sequence $(x_n)$ and yet another sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$, where the individual components are defined by the rule $z_n=ny_n$. At least that's the only way the notation $n(y_n)$ makes sense to me.

So
$$
(z_0,z_1,z_2,\ldots)=(0,f(1),2f(2),3f(3),4f(4),\ldots).
$$

With all this out of the way the answer to the question:

> Is $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}=n(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$?

is an emphatic "No" (in general). Remember that two sequences are equal if and only if all their corresponding components are equal. Let's study this in detail. The equation $z_0=x_0$ implies $f(0)=0$. Given that, the equation
$z_1=x_1$, or $f(1)=f(0)+f(1)$, is then true irrespective of choice of $f(1)$. The equation $z_2=x_2$, or $2f(2)=f(0)+f(1)+f(2)=f(1)+f(2)$ then implies that $f(2)=f(1)$. We can proceed by induction, and conclude that we must have $f(k)=f(1)$ for all $k>1$. So the claimed equality holds only when that condition is met.

---

I dare not guess what the conclusion *and hence $\sum_{i=0}^n= nf(n)$* is trying to claim.

---

May be the following example will make this clearer? Let us defined delayed versions of the sequence $Y=(y_n)$. Define the $k$ times Delayed sequence $D^kY$ by declaring that $(D^kY)_{n+k}=y_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, and $(D^kY)_n=0$ whenever $n<k$. In other words
$$
\begin{aligned}
D^1Y&=(0,y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,\ldots),\\
D^2Y&=(0,0,y_0,y_1,y_2,\ldots),\\
\end{aligned}
$$
and so forth.

When $Y$ is the above sequence, then we get that the sum
$
\sum_{k=0}^mD^kY
$
agrees with the sequence $X=(x_n)$ up to subscript $n=m$. You may have not defined a topology in the sequence space yet, but it is possible to define it in such a way that the infinite sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^kY$ converges, and that sum will then be equal to $X$.

Comment: Way too long to be a comment, so an answer it is. Ping me, if you think it should be deleted.